# Distinct Throws Error (llegalStateException: the keyCoder of a GroupByKey must be deterministic)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

While reading data from bigQuery table using Dataflow Job, trying to avoid duplication in the collection. For that used beam.sdk.transforms.Distinct to read  the record with distinct. But got below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: the keyCoder of a GroupByKey must be deterministic
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:193)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:107)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:471)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:357)
```

Code snippet:

```
PCollection<TableRow> mainData = p.apply("ReadCustomers",BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(options.getCustomers()));
PCollection<TableRow> uniqueCollection = mainData.apply(Distinct.<TableRow>create());
```

Could some one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`TableRow` is not a data type that is certain to be deterministic. For example, if you were to serialize to JSON, the same TableRow-like element may look in these two different ways:

`{"name":"rajan", "language":"java"}` vs `{"language":"java", "name":"rajan"}`

Those are two different **non-deterministic** ways of serializing the exact same object, and thus if you use that data type as a key, it won't be a valid one.

Something you could do instead, is transform your object into key-value pairs that have a deterministic key. For example:

```
PCollection<TableRow> uniqueCollection = p.apply("ReadCustomers",BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                              .from(options.getCustomers()));
 .apply(WithKeys.of(new SerializableFunction<TableRow, Integer>() {
         public Integer apply(TableRow row) { return row.getUniqueId(); } })))
 .apply(Values<TableRow>.create());
```

Comment: From the SerializableFunction, I cannot get "row.getUniqueId()" value from the TableRow collection(syntax error), but I can get rid of the error with row.get("Id").toString(), but still got the same issue while running the dataflow job ("the keyCoder of a GroupByKey must be deterministic"). Anyway I got your point.